# Oracle WCC NoClassDefFoundError: org/xml/sax/EntityResolver when running Apache POI in Custom Component

Tags: java, apache-poi, java-6, oracle-ucm

I'm writing a custom component for **Oracle WCC** to read in and process metadata updates from an Excel file.

However, when my Component tries to read the file with [apache-poi](/questions/tagged/apache-poi) (**version:** 3.11) I get the following exception:

```
!csUserEventMessage,weblogic,localhost:16200!$!csUnableToExecMethod,runTheMassUpdate!syJavaExceptionWrapper,java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/xml/sax/EntityResolver
intradoc.common.ServiceException: !csUnableToExecMethod,runTheMassUpdate
*ScriptStack LOWES_MMU_SERVICE
3:runTheMassUpdate,**no captured values**
        at intradoc.server.ServiceRequestImplementor.buildServiceException(ServiceRequestImplementor.java:2176)
        at intradoc.server.Service.buildServiceException(Service.java:2404)
        at intradoc.server.Service.createServiceExceptionEx(Service.java:2398)
        at intradoc.server.Service.createServiceException(Service.java:2393)
        at intradoc.server.Service.doCodeEx(Service.java:673)
        at intradoc.server.Service.doCode(Service.java:594)
        at intradoc.server.ServiceRequestImplementor.doAction(ServiceRequestImplementor.java:1693)
        at intradoc.server.Service.doAction(Service.java:566)
   /* Lines removed for brevity */
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/xml/sax/EntityResolver
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
        at intradoc.loader.IdcClassLoader.defineClass(IdcClassLoader.java:639)
        at intradoc.loader.IdcClassLoader.findClass(IdcClassLoader.java:794)
        at intradoc.loader.IdcClassLoader.loadClass(IdcClassLoader.java:677)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
        at intradoc.loader.IdcClassLoader.defineClass(IdcClassLoader.java:639)
        at intradoc.loader.IdcClassLoader.findClass(IdcClassLoader.java:794)
        at intradoc.loader.IdcClassLoader.loadClass(IdcClassLoader.java:677)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
        at org.apache.poi.util.SAXHelper.&#60;clinit&#62;(SAXHelper.java:53)
        at org.apache.poi.util.DocumentHelper.newDocumentBuilder(DocumentHelper.java:45)
        at org.apache.poi.util.DocumentHelper.&#60;clinit&#62;(DocumentHelper.java:100)
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.ContentTypeManager.parseContentTypesFile(ContentTypeManager.java:376)
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.ContentTypeManager.&#60;init&#62;(ContentTypeManager.java:102)
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.ZipContentTypeManager.&#60;init&#62;(ZipContentTypeManager.java:54)
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.getPartsImpl(ZipPackage.java:192)
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.getParts(OPCPackage.java:673)
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:226)
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:186)
        at com.lowes.content.edam.massMetaDataUpdate.file.impl.ExcelFileParser.readInputFile(ExcelFileParser.java:162)
```

I've added the library files to my components classpath in the hda file.

```
classpath=$COMPONENT_DIR/classes/:$COMPONENT_DIR/lib/poi-ooxml-3.11.jar:$COMPONENT_DIR/lib/stax-api-1.0.1.jar:$COMPONENT_DIR/lib/xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar:$COMPONENT_DIR/lib/httpcore-4.4.1.jar:$COMPONENT_DIR/lib/jna-4.1.0.jar:$COMPONENT_DIR/lib/guava-11.0.jar:$COMPONENT_DIR/lib/httpmime-4.4.1.jar:$COMPONENT_DIR/lib/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:$COMPONENT_DIR/lib/xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar:$COMPONENT_DIR/lib/poi-3.11.jar:$COMPONENT_DIR/lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar:$COMPONENT_DIR/lib/owasp-java-html-sanitizer-1.1.jar:$COMPONENT_DIR/lib/ooxml-schemas-1.1.jar:$COMPONENT_DIR/lib/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.11.jar:$COMPONENT_DIR/lib/jsr173-1.0.jar:$COMPONENT_DIR/lib/jna-platform-4.1.0.jar:$COMPONENT_DIR/lib/httpclient-4.4.1.jar:$COMPONENT_DIR/lib/jsr305-2.0.1.jar
classpathorder=0
libpath=$COMPONENT_DIR/lib
libpathorder=0
```

**Note:**  the missing class should be being provided by `xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar` which is a maven dependency, and included in the component Classpath, and copied into the lib folder.

So why am I getting the exception? 
Why Can't the server find `org.xml.sax.EntityResolver`?

**further question**
I hope I'm not sending this down the wrong rabbit hole but a former co-worker ran into an issue with the [oracle-ucm](/questions/tagged/oracle-ucm) `IdcClassLoader` when using [apache-fop](/questions/tagged/apache-fop).  Since **fop** uses it's own custom classloader.  Does [apache-poi](/questions/tagged/apache-poi) have the same issue?

---

**Manifest.hda** (component listing)

```
component
LowesMassMetadataUpdater/LowesMassMetadataUpdater.hda
componentExtra
LowesMassMetadataUpdater/readme.md
componentClasses
LowesMassMetadataUpdater/classes/
componentLib
LowesMassMetadataUpdater/lib/
```

Comment: Why are you using quite an old version of Apache POI? What happens when you upgrade to the latest version?

Comment: I'm still running in Java 6.  Does Poi 3.14 / 3.15 support Java 6?

Comment: Hey! I'm the co-worker that had trouble with the IdcClassLoader.  IIRC the issue was with how plugins were loaded by getResource method of the classloader. The 'findResource' of the base class and IdcClassLoader is to return a blank enumeration. 'findResource' of the default UrlClassLoader (which is what FOP expects) searches the entire classpath for said resource. I think this case may be caused by something else.

Comment: @Raystorm POI 3.11-3.15 all work fine with Java 6. No decisions taken yet on bumping up to Java 7, so likely 3.16+ should be fine too once those exist!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>Check your manifest.hda and make sure the 'Component Name'/libs is added as a componentExtra or componentLib otherwise those libs libraries won't be deployed to the content server's filesystem on component install (and hence the classes won't be resolved at runtime). You can check this assumption if you peer into the filesystem of the user_project's WCC instance in question.</s>

The classloader probably has classes from one SAX implementation already loaded. Try removing the xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar from your classpath completely. I'd wager there's already a competing SAX implementation in the classpath that is compatible.

Comment: I have it as **componentLib**, not **ComponentExtra** See my updated question for more info.

Comment: Gah, that isn't it... It would have failed sooner (when loading the POI classes)... sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Try to find the Jar file that is being used by the system. There might be a dependency conflict. You can use the following check in your `com.lowes.content.edam.massMetaDataUpdate.file.impl.ExcelFileParser` class:

```
System.out.println(EntityResolver.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation());
```

This will locate the owner Jar file of the class. Your SAX is most probably being loaded from an older (or newer?) library, where the EntityResolver is still (or already) absent.

Comment: That was a helpful suggestion, it actually threw a new error.  
`java.lang.LinkageError: Class org/xml/sax/EntityResolver violates loader constraints`  
Looks like there is some internal conflict I need to track down.

Comment: It seems that the SAX version where the EntityResolver is introduced, requires java 7 as a minimum. I might be wrong though

Comment: The reference to the class of the EntityResolver will throw the linkage error due to the NoClassDefFound.  It was there when the class was compiled, but not at runtime, so both errors are expected.  The difference here is the static reference to the class causes a LinkageError.

Comment: @AaronRomine  The static log line actually logs a location for the EntityResolver class.  It's the next where I call Apache POI.  `OPCPackage.open(fileName);` that causes the `LinkageError` to be thrown.  The log actually contains:  `EntityResolver.class Location: file:/home/oracle/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/base_domain/ucm/cs/custom/LowesMassMetadataUpdater/lib/xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar` Which is the expected location for the class.

Comment: Interesting.  It's definitely a dependency problem then.  Try removing the xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar from your classpath completely.  I'd wager there's already a competing SAX implementation in the classpath.

Comment: @AaronRomine removing that dependency worked.  I'm now making progress against new and different errors.

Answer (score 0):

I searched for the class *org.xml.sax.EntityResolver* in http://search.maven.org
and could see that the missing class is in sax-2.0.1.jar

Please download the jar and add it to your classpath.
http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|fc%3A%22org.xml.sax.EntityResolver%22

Please also read the question: [Why am I getting a NoClassDefFoundError in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java)

Comment: I have `xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar` on my classpath and bundled in my *lib* folder.  It also provides the `org.xml.sax.EntityResolver` class.

Comment: OK. I see that `xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar` is also fine.
Sorry, but than it must be something different.

What is that 'intradoc' in the stacktrace?
` at intradoc.loader.IdcClassLoader.defineClass(IdcClassLoader.java:639)`

Comment: Intradoc is an Oracle wrapper that comes with its class loader, and most probably does its bad job with the protection domain of user class libraries. The same tool might prefer some other (<2.0.1) version of SAX, that overrides the users SAX library.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your *classpath* should be separated by semi-colons (not colons).
2. Do you have an *InstallID* set in the Build Settings of your
   component?

[Here](https://bitbucket.org/jhult/pdfpagenumbers/src/6f039c1a711ed7f5bb9fac7ed8b958c38110eae8/PDFPageNumbers.hda?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default) is an example of a component .hda file.

Comment: in a normal Java classpath it's **;** on Windows and **:** on Linux/Unix.  My WCC install is running under **Oracle Linux.** is an *HDA classpath* different?

And yes an InstallID is set.

Comment: I've only ever seen ; in use but : might work. Try both and see if that helps.

Have you ensured the lib folder is added to the component (either as a componentLib or as a componentExtra)?

Comment: This is entirely dependent on the platform's PATH_SEPARATOR value.  I believe WCC component class paths get fixed up before resolution either way though.  Threw me off the first time I saw it as well, but it works the same either way.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling the *ReportPublisher* component. It appears to have the same libraries in it.